# End browser session using Cucumber and Capybara

Tags: session, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I am running into a problem.  I'm currently testing a webpage that has a security feature built in that will not allow more than 3 concurrent logins to the same user Id at any given time.  I am finding that when I am running my tests and a scenario fails, a new window opens for the next test but the session is still valid.  3 failures will then lock out that user for the allocated amount of time.

Is there a way that I can tell Cucumber to kill the session if the test fails to avoid this? Otherwise I'm faced with a 15 minute wait to resume testing.

Thank you

Comment: bit confused, does it open new window for next test of same test class or it opens new window for next test class?

Comment: It opens a new browser window for every new scenario that it's running.  What I'm finding is, when the test fails, it goes red and then starts the next scenario in a new window.  The previous session stills seems to be active and the server thinks that previous user is still logged in.  If this happens on 3 consecutive occasions, the system locks out that user until one of the sessions ends.

Comment: As a result, all subsequent tests related to that user will fail as they can't be logged in

Answer (score 0):

These links might helps you.

https://github.com/grosser/parallel_tests

https://www.npmjs.com/package/parallel-cucumber